# How Should I Pray When Alone?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, tzibur-community

Using the notes in my Siddurs to direct my prayers, I am trying to figure out exactly what to pray, what is required, what is not permissible, etc., when praying solo. There is not always the right answer for the question I have.

Is there any primer on praying alone that would answer the large variety of questions I might have about praying alone?

Comment: What siddur are you using? Some siddurim probably do a fine job.

Comment: I find that the Art Scroll Siddur as well as Rabbi Sacks' Koren siddur do a good job.

Comment: @DoubleAA. I am actually using both listed here by (Artscroll and Koren). it may be best for me to ask about specifics if there is not a primer.

Comment: @sabbahillel see my last comment.

Comment: I've heard good things about the book "To Pray As A Jew."

Comment: @msh210 dont understand the question, one uses the same prayers as one says in the synagogue

Comment: I see from an answer the question really is what not to say what is printed in the siddur. That makes more sense.

Comment: You could make the question broader and better by asking what a woman (who usually davens at home) should not say.

Comment: You don't recite or you may not recite

Comment: @preferred I don't see how that would be better or broader. The question now is gender- and location-neutral.

Comment: @Double AA Its better because its lchatchila.

Comment: Prayer by definition is never in isolation. Hashem is always present when prayer is spoken. Keep that in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [this page](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/541770/jewish/Which-prayers-are-omitted-when-praying-alone.htm). This is the summary:

> In conclusion, you do not recite:
>
> 1. Kaddish.
> 2. Barchu.
> 3. The additional prayers recited during the chazzan's repetition of the amidah.
> 4. G d's attributes of mercy.
> 5. Any of the prayers that are associated with the reading of the Torah.
>
> Other than the above mentioned prayers, you can recite everything
>   which is recited when praying as part of a congregation.

Comment: Although the kedusha before shma (kedushas yotsair) can be said alone. This opinion is not universal and should be said with  the chazan. In other words the chazan should stop before it. Even people praying with minyan should be aware of this.

Comment: This also applies to the kedusha of 'uvo lzion'.

Comment: @DoubleAA you don't recite Hallel without a minyan.  Between Rosh Chodesh, chagim, chol hamoed, and Chanukah this comes up around 50 days a year, so I thought it worth a mention.

Comment: @Monica I am not aware of such a general rule. I have heard of skipping hallel when alone on days where only half hallel is recited.

Comment: @DoubleAA thanks, interesting.  The minyan where I mostly go skips hallel (either type) if there's no minyan and I thought that was the rule, but I've never looked for a source.

Comment: @MonicaCellio http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=3233 says “One May say Hallel alone and at home if necessary.”
The site quoted above has a comment “What about Hallel?
.. I am fond of a Sefaradi sidur (Bnei Tzion) where it says that Hallel (113-118) is said only with minian ...”
http://halachahbyemail.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/minyan-for-hallel-on-rosh-chodesh.html says “In truth, the requirement is not for a minyan, per se; even having three people present, so that one leads "Hodu" and the others respond, may suffice. (Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 422:2; Mishneh Berurah 422:18)”.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok thanks!  I withdraw the objection.  (I had already upvoted the answer.)

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok. Thank you, very useful and direct answer, and even better this supports what I have read about it. Gives me reassurance about what I have been doing.

Comment: Re: the attributes of mercy, if you're referring to what's said in Tachanun, a person praying on his own cannot recite that passage in a prayerful fashion, but can still read it - with te'amim, and as though he is reading it from the Torah.