Halachot on Davening as a Yachid
I have a siddur app called Smart Siddur, and it has a "Yachid" mode, for when davening alone. I had to use it recently due to a family illness*, and it got me curious about halachot for davening  as a yachid (rather than with a minyan, which one should do whenever possible). For example, the passage from Zohar beginning "חיה אחת עומדת" is said instead of "ברכו את ה' המבורך", and I see this brought down in the Ben Ish Chai, and Kaf HaChaim.
Is there a good article or even more classic work collecting all of the halachot and other useful information regarding men davening alone? I prefer sefardi but I would be happy to see anything relevant.
* please daven for Micha'el Ben Miriam for a refua shelema

Which nusach are you using ? My nusach (Nusach Ashkenaz) has no substitution for ברכו, although some say the replacement in Selgmann Baer's Seder Avaudass Jisroel

@NoachMiFrankfurt Edot Mizrach

Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37826/759

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/113329/origins-of-kaddish-yachid

Refuah shleima!

I remember having seen such a guide during the lockdown...

There are many guides within the nusachot of the Jews from Teiman too, like for example the Kadish to be recited when davening alone. See Siddur Siach Yerushalayim and Tiklal Tefillot Avot.

How’s מיכאל doing?

This response by Rabbi David Sperling addresses Nusach Ashkenaz https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/6453
Summary:
In general the parts of the service you need to leave out when praying by yourself are those that need a minyan, which are  kaddish, saying "Barechu", the repetition of the Amidah and the Torah reading.
So, for Shacharit you could say everything except the kaddishes, the repetition of the Amidah, and the Torah reading (that is you skip from where it says "Removal Of The Torah From The Ark" up to where it says "Ashrei – Uva L'Tzion").
For Mincha, you would say Ashrei, then straight away the Amidah, tachanun and Alainu.
And for Ma'ariv, [after saying "v'hu rachum" (see comments below)] start from the line after "Barechu" (which needs a minyan to say) and say until the kaddish before the Amidah - which you will leave out - then the Amidah, and Alainu. All mourner's kaddishes are also omitted in all services.
This article by Rabbi Eliezer Posner addresses Nusach Ari (Chabad) https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/541770/jewish/Which-prayers-are-omitted-when-praying-alone.htm
Summary:
In conclusion, you do not recite:

Kaddish.

Barchu.

The additional prayers recited during the chazzan's repetition of the amidah.

G d's attributes of mercy.

Any of the prayers that are associated with the reading of the Torah.


Other than the above mentioned prayers, you can recite everything which is recited when praying as part of a congregation.
This article Davening Alone: Laws and Details by Rabbi Yehoshua Pfeffer at https://dinonline.org/2020/03/27/davening-alone-laws-and-details/ provides additional material including the following:
"As noted above, when davening alone one does not recite Kaddish and Kedusha. Nor does one say Barchu or hold a reading of the Torah with its blessings. But what about the words, “Kadosh, Kadosh, Kadosh” and “Baruch Kevod Hashem Mimkomo” in the blessings before the Shema and at the end of davening in the kedusha de’sidra? Can these be said as usual when davening alone?
"There is a discussion among Poskim concerning reciting these words when davening alone. The Shulchan Aruch (59:3) notes two opinions concerning whether the Pesukim can be recited, and therefore recommends saying then with their notes, as when reading from the Torah. The Rema rules that the words can be said alone, as usual, but the Mishnah Berurah (59:11) writes that one should follow the ruling of the Shulchan Aruch. Somebody who knows the “trup” (the notes) should therefore say the words with the notes."

Are you saying to skip הוא רחום in maariv?

@magicker72 Thank you for pointing that out. I have added in "[after saying "v'hu rachum"]" in the maariv paragraph

You should make clear that that part is not from your source. And if you needed to add that in, it doesn't give great confidence in your source.

This answer is a good general guide of the general halachos. If you stumble upon any interesting tidbits like the Chaya achat in my OP, or alternatives for 13 middot, or other interesting suggestions, please add them in
